# Nomad job constraint: run on list of nodes

Tags: nomad

I'm trying to find a way to run a Nomad job on a specific set of machines identified by IP address. I have looked at the documentation on the [constraint block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/constraint), but I can't find a way to achieve this. Ideally, it would look something like:

```
job "myjob" {
  type = "sysbatch"

  constraint {
    attribute = "${attr.unique.network.ip-address}"
    operator  = "attribute_included_in"
    value     = "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
  }

  group "sys_batch_job" {
    # ...
  }
}
```

The operators `set_contains` and `set_contains_any` are both intended for scenarios where the attribute itself contains a list of values. I tried using the `regexp` operator, but it also doesn't work. Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert your thinking.

```
  constraint {
    attribute = "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
    operator  = "set_contains"
    value     = "${attr.unique.network.ip-address}"
  }
```

Comment: Interesting idea, it doesn't seem to work - it resulted in a placement error. Edit: wait, I was running in the wrong datacenter. This works!